# How to make an automated test which checks that no components in a React component tree re-rendered?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, automated-tests, cypress, react-test-renderer

I want to automate the following test scenario:

1. I render some arbitrary React component tree.
2. I make some action (scroll some container / click a button / ...)
3. I assert if any components have re-rendered since taking action `2.`

What would be a good way to do this? We currently use `Jest`, `Cypress` and `react-test-renderer` in our project - it would be great to find a way to this using those. But this is not strictly necessary.

I need this to catch improperly memoized `useSelector` calls high up the component tree, which result in most of the app re-rendering - we keep running into this problem over and over.

Comment: Are you intending to use Component Testing? Please add what you have already tried, and the code that is likely to re-render. The question lacks debugging details.

Comment: I would prefer a component test, but it doesn't have to be - a Cypress scenario running on full app would be OK too.

Comment: There's this https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render. Could use that in a test environment.

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR As for the second part of your question: I have not tried anything, I'm asking for a good way to achieve this. I know a bit about React testing, but have no idea how to tackle this. I disagree this question lacks debugging details. It has none, because there is nothing to debug. I asked for a working approach that works with any abstract component. I see no benefit in providing an example, when I'm asking for an abstract solution.

Comment: I described the scenario with `I need this to catch improperly memoized useSelector calls high up the component tree`. In my opinion, this really says all - much more than an example code, at least to those potentially capable of answering my question. This question is targeted for people familiar with React and testing. If, from this description, you are (or anyone else is) not sure **exactly** what I'm pointing at, then this question is just not targeted at you. I find it to be very simple for anyone familiar with the subject, and very foreign for anyone who is not.

Comment: What you say applies to ***any*** question - you probably already know this, but it is too general for SO, the kind of question that cannot be answered precisely and therefore invites endless discussion about the details. This question is not within the guidelines, should be closed.

Comment: @GerhardFunk I do not see how this cannot be answered precisely and invites endless discussion about details. There are many questions on SO that which allow for multiple solutions, each of them being valid. This is one of them. I will accept any answer which describes a way to achieve what I'm asking for, and have defined precisely. I believe that detecting a re-render of an arbitrary React component in test environment is a very specific issue, and providing example code would add nothing to the question.

Comment: I've added an answer, let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @morganney, [welldone-software/why-did-you-render](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render) has a bunch of Cypress test examples already in the project.

Here is one example:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('visitAndSpyConsole', (url, cb) => {
  const context = {};

  cy.visit(url, {
    onBeforeLoad: win => {
      cy.spy(win.console, 'log');
      cy.spy(win.console, 'group');
    },
    onLoad: win => context.win = win,
  });

  cy.waitFor(context.win)
    .then(() => cb(context.win.console));
});

it('Child of Pure Component', () => {
  cy.visitAndSpyConsole('/#childOfPureComponent', console => {
    cy.contains('button', 'clicks:').click();
    cy.contains('button', 'clicks:').click();
  
    cy.contains('button', 'clicks:').should('contain', '2');

    expect(console.group).to.be.calledWithMatches([
      { match: 'PureFather', times: 2 },
      { match: /props.*children\W/, times: 2 },
    ]);

    expect(console.log).to.be.calledWithMatches([
      { match: 'syntax always produces a *NEW* immutable React element', times: 2 },
    ]);
  });
});
```

If you add more details to the question, I can give you a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

Generally re-render checks'/optimisation's are done at development time using Reacts Profiler API.

https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html

this tells you why something re-rendered, times re-rendered.

**EDIT@2**

I was reading a blog and i found a better way to integrate it into a test.

In my last approach you would have to have a callback to log and a babel-plugin to wrap your desired component for test.

with approach 2 you can just use -

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(
  <Link page="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</Link>
   );

console.log(testRenderer.toJSON());
// { type: 'a',
//   props: { href: 'https://www.facebook.com/' },
//   children: [ 'Facebook' ] }
```

it prints out host(in your case react) component tree in json, You can use Jest’s snapshot testing feature to automatically save a copy of the JSON tree and check if anything has changes and compute your rerenders.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Kartik :). I know this, but It would be very tedious to manually investigate in every PR if a huge part of UI didn't start needlessly re-rendering as a result of a poorly memoized selector, or something like that. That's why I need an automated test which can alert me when this occurs.

Comment: This comment is an exact example of why the question is too vague. The profiler has a re-render callback that can be used to count occurrences. Yet you dismiss the idea out of hand.

Comment: @GerhardFunk It may have, and I thank you for noting this. I will look into hooking into it in a test environment. Unlike what you have said, the answer itself did not directly mention anything relevant to the use-case I described in my question. It mentioned the same tool, but nothing about its relevance to my use-case! I dismissed the idea of "re-render checks'/optimisation's done at development time", because I explicitely asked for a different use-case (automated testing). I did not dismiss a use-case that was not in any way referenced in the answer and I did not know of.

Comment: @GerhardFunk Ok, I made a mistake here. I did dismiss this answer prematurely. I did not open the link, and thought OP was talking about the Profiler devtools functionality. That was silly/arrogant/... of me. But I believe this has everything to do with me, and nothing to do with the question being "vague".

Comment: Hi @GerhardFunk, i have edited the solution with a newer approach

Comment: Hi @MichalKurz, i have edited the solution with a newer approach

Comment: @KartikRana Thank you very much for your time and input! The Profiler approach should work well - although it seems like it could be easily substituted with a simple custom component which calls the callback inside a `useEffect`. The `Profiler` components seems to provide no benefits over that for my described use-case - but still, it can be used to solve my problem, if I provide the callback via React Context inside my test scenario. And it seems much more straight-forward, than the wdyr approach suggested in the other answer :)

Comment: @KartikRana As for your edit and comments: I don't see why you would need a `babel-plugin` - maybe as an alternative approach to providing callback via React Context? But I think you can do just fine without it. :) The `.toJSON()` approach however doesn't seem to work, because it cannot detect redundant re-renders which result in the same DOM state, but can still be very expensive ... which is the main use-case here, as described in my question, by saying i'm after "improperly memoized `useSelector` calls" :)

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for your problem.

The first one is implemented with Puppeteer **only**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/path-to-your-page')
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1276, height: 689 });
  await navigationPromise;

  // Begin profiling...
  await page.tracing.start({ path: 'profiling-results.json' });
  // do action
  await page.$eval('.class_name:last-child', e => {
   e.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'end' });
  });

  // Stop profliling
  await page.tracing.stop();

  await browser.close();
})()
```

The second one is implemented with Puppeteer and the use of React Profiler API directly in your app:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/path-to-your-page')
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1276, height: 689 });
  await navigationPromise;

    page
.on('console', message =>
  console.log(`${message.type().substr(0, 3).toUpperCase()} ${message.text()}`))

  // do action
  await page.$eval('.class_name:last-child or any other CSS selector/id/etc', e => {
   e.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'end' });
  });

  await browser.close();
})()
```

And for the second solution to work add this code to your App.jsx:

```
<Profiler
                      id="profile-all"
                      onRender={
                          (id, phase, actualDuration) => {
                          console.log({id, phase, actualDuration})
                          }
                      }>
{/*all of the markdown should go inside*/}
</Profiler>
```

Comment: There're many other different ways to do this, let me know if it helps, or what should be changed in the solution so it fits your needs